# Convert Pandas DataFrame to CSV but only export specific columns

Tags: python, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have a pandas dataframe which has 8 columns which I need to write to CSV, it`s working perfectly but I just want specific columns of my dataframeto be converted to csv. How to do that

```
from pandas import DataFrame
data = DataFrame.from_dict(diction)
data_to_write = data[["channel_id", "channel_img", "desc"]]`

{'data': [{'channel_id': 'UCqTFe5Dz3mpixUrLfMmY6dw', 'title': 'Manoyek', 
'channel_img': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAx- 
JBOt1_NI6nXTBL2R95kDBaR6Spy9i4_q-g=s240-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'desc': 
'Jestem Adrian' , 'subscriberCount_gained': 587372, 'subscriberCount_lost': 
0}]}
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have columns. Can you provide a **[mcve]**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

dictionary = {'data': [{'channel_id': 'UCqTFe5Dz3mpixUrLfMmY6dw', 'title': 'Manoyek', 'channel_img': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAx-JBOt1_NI6nXTBL2R95kDBaR6Spy9i4_q-g=s240-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'desc': 'Jestem Adrian' , 'subscriberCount_gained': 587372, 'subscriberCount_lost': 0}]}

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary["data"])

data_to_write = data[["channel_id", "channel_img", "desc"]]
data_to_write.to_csv("filename.csv")
```

Comment: Its says KeyError not in index

Comment: Please provide this in your question and please provide also example of diction

Comment: Done please check

Comment: ...and also example of diction :)

Comment: I need to clarify the keys of your dictionary. Are there ["channel_id", "channel_img", "desc"]?

Comment: Please check. Edited

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas!

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(dictionary).to_csv('filename.csv')
```